# If contributor has published 2 or more posts then show otherwise hide

Tags: posts, author

If the contributor has already published two or more posts I show a maximum of 5 of them in the post-single.php using this code

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[latestbyauthor show="5"]'); ?>
```

I have a text that introduces the code (other posts by the same author)

This works fine if the contributor really has published 2 or more article but totally uselless if he has just one post.

What I'm looking is a way to hide the text before the code by checking the total number of posts published, if 1 then hide and if 2 then show.

Is it possible?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simpler than using the `$wpdb` class would be to use [`count_user_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/count_user_posts).  For instance:

```
$min_posts = 2;
if( count_user_posts( $post->post_author ) >= $min_posts ) {
    // display the user's posts
}
```

This assumes you're in The Loop, or at the very least that `$post` is a WordPress Post object.

[above edited 2013-03-19 11:30 AM CDT]

Note that if you're trying to count custom post types (and possibly pages, though I'm not sure), you'll need to use some `$wpdb` magic, but there's a code sample available at the Codex page for `count_user_posts()` (linked above).

Comment: I'm not good at php...
I tried
`<?php
$min_posts = 2;
if( count_user_posts( $author_id ) > $min_posts ) {
echo "Other posts from the same user";    // display the user's posts
}
?>`
with no luck as it keeps showing the text even if the author has published only one post...

Comment: What are you using as `$author_id`? If it's an un-initialised value, it may be comparing in correctly and giving a false positive.

Comment: I've updated my code sample, replacing `$author_id` with `$post->post_author`, and also changing the `>` comparison to `>=` so that you'll catch authors with exactly 2 posts.

Answer (score 0):

You could run a query to grab an array of the number of posts by each author, and then check that array. This is untested, so may need tweeking (a Google search of 'mysql count occurrences of value' should also yield some results.

```
$query = 'SELECT post_author, COUNT(*) as count FROM wp_posts GROUP BY post_author ORDER BY count DESC'
$author_count = $wpdb->get_col($query);
```

Then, when you are checking the number of posts by that author -

```
if($author_count($author_id)) > 1) : // Where $author_id is the ID of the Author being shown
    // Do whatever here...
endif;
```

Finally, if you get an error, you may need to add `global $wpdb;` just before the `$query = ...` line

Comment: Forgive me but running a query seems to be beyond my possibilities...
I hoped it was just a matter of adding that code in functions.php...